# Bluetooth not working after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, laptop, bluetooth

I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. After upgrading the Bluetooth is not working. It shows 'No adapters found'. My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 R. How can i Get the driver??

Comment: *Wrong question.* This is not *Windows*, and you may not need a driver. Look at other questions tagged **bluetooth**.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned model number correctly after 15R-?.

Click on this [link](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/in/en/indhs1/Product/inspiron-15r-5521) and select operating system and system type to download drivers Inspiron 15R 5521 , If your model is not this click [here](http://www.dell.com/support/my-support/in/en/indhs1/product-support/product) and select your model and do the same.